# Angular modal service error - TypeError: modal.element.modal is not a function

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I have problem with an angular [modal service](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service)

My app.js includes:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.test', 'ui.bootstrap','smart-table''angularModalService','ngRoute','myApp.productInsert',...
```

test.js:

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.test', ['angularModalService'])



 .controller('ComplexController', [
  '$scope', '$element', 'title', 'close', 
  function($scope, $element, title, close) {

  $scope.name = null;
  $scope.age = null;
  $scope.title = title;

  //  This close function doesn't need to use jQuery or bootstrap, because
  //  the button has the 'data-dismiss' attribute.
  $scope.close = function() {
      close({
      name: $scope.name,
      age: $scope.age
    }, 500); // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
  };

  //  This cancel function must use the bootstrap, 'modal' function because
  //  the doesn't have the 'data-dismiss' attribute.
  $scope.cancel = function() {

    //  Manually hide the modal.
    $element.modal('hide');

    //  Now call close, returning control to the caller.
    close({
      name: $scope.name,
      age: $scope.age
    }, 500); // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
  };

}]);
```

And then test.html

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close()" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Here's a more complex modal, it contains a form, data is passed to the controller 
         and data is returned from the modal.</p>

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" ng-model="name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Age" ng-model="age">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" ng-click="close()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="cancel()" class="btn">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the main page that opens modal windows

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.ricetta2', ['ngRoute', 'angularModalService','ui.bootstrap'])

        .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/ricetta2', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/ricetta/ricetta2.html',
                    controller: 'CartForm'
                });
            }])

        .controller('CartForm', ['$scope','ModalService', function($scope, ModalService) {
                $scope.invoice = {
                    items: [{
                            qty: 10,
                            description: 'Pomodori',
                            cost: 'Kg'}, {
                            qty: 10,
                            description: 'Olio',
                            cost: 'litri'}, {
                            qty: 4,
                            description: 'Pasta',
                            cost: 'Kg'}]
                };

                $scope.addItem = function() {
                    $scope.invoice.items.push({
                        qty: 1,
                        description: '',
                        cost: ''
                    });
                },
                        $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
                            $scope.invoice.items.splice(index, 1);

                        },
                        $scope.total = function() {
                            var total = 0;
                            angular.forEach($scope.invoice.items, function(item) {
                                total += item.qty * item.cost;
                            });

                            return total;
                        };

                $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
                $scope.productList = [];



              $scope.showComplex = function() {

                    ModalService.showModal({
                        templateUrl: "views/test/test.html",
                        controller: "ComplexController",
                        inputs: {
                            title: "A More Complex Example"
                        }
                    }).then(function(modal) {
                        modal.element.modal();
                        modal.close.then(function(result) {
                            $scope.complexResult = "Name: " + result.name + ", age: " + result.age;
                        });
                    });

                };


            }]);
```

When I try to open Modal windows I have always an error on the page:

> TypeError: modal.element.modal is not a function
>       at ricetta2.js:60
>       at processQueue (angular.js:13248)
>       at angular.js:13264
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14466)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14282)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
>       at done (angular.js:9698)
>       at completeRequest (angular.js:9888)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:9829)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11655$get @ angular.js:8596processQueue @ angular.js:13256(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13264$get.Scope.$eval @ angular.js:14466$get.Scope.$digest @ angular.js:14282$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:14571done @ angular.js:9698completeRequest @ angular.js:9888requestLoaded @ angular.js:9829

I have all the resources linked on the index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="bower_components/angular-modal-service/dst/angular-modal-service.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'm very new to angularjs and I don't know the solution!!

Thanks all

Comment: In your `app.js` you are missing a comma between two of the dependencies `smart-table''angularModalService',`

Comment: in my  code comma is present, it is not present only in stackoverflow section, so this is not the error .

Comment: @Andrea I think you have to add bootstrap.js or bootstrap/modal.js as depencency.

Comment: look at bottom of the page "I'm using a Bootstrap Modal and the dialog doesn't show up" section - https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service

also: https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service/issues/14

Comment: I have bootstrap.js loading before angular and still get "TypeError: modal.element.modal is not a function" I can even click on it in the HTML and it opens, so I know bootstrap.js is loading. Maybe its a version disharmony?

Answer (score 17):

I had same problem. Interchanging the script tags locations solved my problem. At first I had script tags in this sequence

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Then I changed it to this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Many times these things happen. Conflicts occur because of loading AngularJS before jQuery.

Comment: I was missing the `bootstrap.js` dependency.

Answer (score 4):

Hi here is the correct detailed solution from https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-modal-service

I'm using a Bootstrap Modal and the dialog doesn't show up

Code is entered exactly as shown the example but when the showAModal() function fires the modal template html is appended to the body while the console outputs:

TypeError: undefined is not a function
Pointing to the code: modal.element.modal();. This occurs if you are using a Bootstap modal but have not included the Bootstrap JavaScript. The recommendation is to include the modal JavaScript before AngularJS.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is incorrect. I'm submitting a PR for the examples.

In the meantime change to this:

```
.then( function(modal)
 {
     modal.element.show();
 });
```

Comment: Our 4 years old version used `modal.element.modal`, and the documentation today still says `modal.element.modal`.  The current working jsfiddle also uses `modal.element.modal`.  Can you provide a link to the issue or PR that you are referring to?

Answer (score 2):

**angularModalService** requires **bootstrap js** 
You already loaded **bootstrap.js** and **jquery.js**
You have to load **jquery.js** first and then **bootstarp.js** and then **angular.js** .
So your resources linked in index.html should be..

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="bower_components/angular-modal-service/dist/angular-modal-service.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you just need to put in order your external js apis
first -> jQuery.js second -> Boostrap.js -> Angular.js like this**

```
<script src="../../resources/js/jquery.js"  th:src="@{/resources/js/jquery.js}"></script>   
<script src="../../resources/js/bootstrap.js"  th:src="@{/resources/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>
<script src="../../resources/js/angular.js"  th:src="@{/resources/js/angular.js}"></script>
<script src="../../resources/js/angular-modal-service.js" th:src="@{/resources/js/angular-modal-service.js}" ></script>
```

Sorry for this tag "th:src" I am using thymeleaf :)

Answer (score -2):

Now i faced similar issue and it was fixed with adding below script files at the top of html.
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"
src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"